# Using Return From One Function To Another Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Here is my code:

```
def options():
    wanted_float = float(input("Wanted Float: "))
    specificity = float(input("How close to float (ex: .001): "))
    low_output = float(input("Min Float of Output Skin: "))
    high_output = float(input("Max Float of Output Skin: "))
    needed_average = ((wanted_float-low_output)/(high_output-low_output))
    print("Needed average: ", needed_average)
    only_lower = input("Only show floats lower than previous? yes/no: ")
    which = input("Would you like to load floats manually or automatically? (manual/automatic): ")
    return which

def mode(which):
    if (mode == 'manual'):
        print("Manual")

    if (mode == 'automatic'):
        print("automatic")

def start():
    options()
    mode(which)

start()
```

However, I keep getting errors. I looked at some other responses dealing with this but they didn't seem to apply to this.

```
Wanted Float: .5
How close to float (ex: .001): .001
Min Float of Output Skin: 0
Max Float of Output Skin: 1
Needed average:  0.5
Only show floats lower than previous? yes/no: yes
Would you like to load floats manually or automatically? (manual/automatic): manual
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.Anderson\Documents\Python\floats\organized.py", line 172, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\.Anderson\Documents\Python\floats\organized.py", line 161, in start
    mode(which)
NameError: name 'which' is not defined
```

The reason it says line 172 and 161 is because I have a lot of other code in between, but I'm only calling options and mode in the start which is all the code does currently

Comment: Simply do `mode(options())`. You may want to read up on variables and scopes

Comment: What errors? Post a stack trace please.

Comment: Or `which = options()`.

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai I added the error

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you did not save the return of `options` function.

You can do it like:

```
mode(options())
```

or

```
which = options()
mode(which)
```